# Amazon mws products weight and confirm an order

Tags: amazon-mws

I am a nodejs developer. My server should ask every x ms and retrieve new orders. Notifications will be sent by the client part of the service to the seller. I need some fields of the order, I use the order api for most fields, the report api to retrieve the telephone number, which is not retrieved by the order api.

What I need now is the list of all the products of the seller, with the properties: SKU, weight

What api should I better use?

I also want to confirm the order shipment by sending to Amazon also a tracking code, but I did not fine this in the apis. Is there this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is periodically download orders into my own system using the reports API.  I have the complete order with header information including all SKU's on the order.  The Orders API is subject to throttling which may affect you.

To update Amazon that your order has shipped and to send a tracking number, you will use the [Feeds API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/feeds/index.html).  Look at the Feed Types, specifically:

```
_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_
```

In the link above, there is a flowchart explaining the process.

Comment: try http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html.  The weight should be under ItemDimensions

Comment: and please mark this as the answer if you are happy with it :)

Comment: Thank you very much, _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ was exactly what I needed. I will continue with orders api, I prefer that, I have already faced the throttling problem. The problem is that I still can't find a method to have the item weight. Actually I do not use report api because it reports order at min every 15 min., with order api, if there are not too much orders and next tokens, I can use it every minute. Thank you again, you saved me lots of time with _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_

Comment: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProductForId.html Can be what I need, the problem is that I need to have all products sku and weights given a sellerId or marketplaceId. So I would need a way to get all seller products sku and then make that call for each one of them. 

Comment: I wrote a batch job where I could input some ASIN's or SKUs into it and it would one-by-one call the MWS product API to get product details.  Then I would add those to my system.  Periodically I would refresh my database with what was on Amazon.  All depends on your use case, but yeah, you need a loop with a call for each ASIN.